# Hibernate & EhCache: net.sf.ehcache.Statistics not populated?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ehcache

I think my Hibernate (3.5.3) Second Level Cache is well configured with EhCache (2.2).

At least, I observe following log entries:

```
20:15:28 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.Cache#searchInStoreWithStats] persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.ActionCache: persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.Action store hit for c.u.p.model.Action#TRT    
20:15:28 DEBUG [net.sf.ehcache.Cache#searchInStoreWithStats] persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.ActionCache: persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.Action store hit for c.u.p.model.Action#PID
```

(*... do these **"store hits"** really indicate that the cache is working?*)

What puzzles me now is:

When I inspect the statistics as follows:

```
cacheManager.getCache("persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.Action").getStatistics().toString()
```

... all I see is:

```
 name = persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.Action cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0
```

... no hits, no misses,... nothing...

In `ehcache.xml`, I have:

```
   <defaultCache
        ...
        statistics="true"
        ...
        />

   <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.Action"
        maxElementsInMemory="100"
        eternal="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        statistics="true"
        />
```

Does this ring a bell to any body?  Do I have to enable statistics in another location as well? ...

---

*Update:*

**persistence.xml** specifies:

```
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird indeed, these debug statement do mean you are having hits to the ersistence.unit:unitName=#pu-pay.c.u.p.model.Action Cache… I wonder whether your CacheManager is the right one, could it be the Hibernate Provider is using another instance ?

How does your hibernate config look like ?

Comment: Thx for the reply Alex.  I don't have a hibernate config.  (It is all driven from a persistence.xml and JPA annotations.)  I have added a persistence.xml snippet to the original question.

Comment: Right, so you are using EhCacheRegionFactory, might be you want to specify a specific ehcache config file, if so you should set the  net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName prop. Otherwise, wasn't the SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory you were looking for ?

Comment: How do you get hold of that cacheManager instance ?

Comment: Sorry for slow response...     CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();     ...    too obvious? :-)

Comment: I think you'd still want to use the SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory for "correctness", but that's what you should already be doing, since you don't configure the EhCacheRegionFactory properly… Can you nevertheless do that change and see if it helps. AFAICT, not providing the net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName props, it'd fallback to the SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory. Could it be hibernate is bootstrapped using some other classloader ?
Could be I'm totally wrong, but this just feels like 2 different CacheManagers: also can you hit the cache programmatically ? Are stats recorded ?